# IIS SMTP : is it a real SMTP server or does it only relay?

Tags: windows, smtp

I was trying to understand if the SMTP virtual server in IIS can only relay mails or if it can act as the final SMTP server. All the tutorials I've found on how to configure it always show it acting as a relay.

Answer (score 0):

It can delivery directly mails (SMTP Server) also relay them

Comment: Could you suggest a resource (article maybe video) on how to configure it as a SMTP server. I understand that this is old stuff but I can't seem to find anything useful/exhaustive on how to implement it as a full SMTP server.